# Comparing A String To Integer, Not Working?

Tags: java

Basically I am developing a program that involves matrices, I am AWARE AND DO NOT CORRECT that the matrix provided can be a simple array but that disproves what I am going for here.

Anyways the code provided below supplies 3 methods that each have a code that I have tried to compare the two values and in each case, it fails. If anyone can point out the error, that would be great.

public class TestingLength {

```
public static String[][] locatedNum = {{"1","2","3"}};

public static int num = 3;

public static void test() {

    System.out.println("Finding Number " + locatedNum[0][2] + " With Number " + num);

    if(locatedNum[0][2] == ""+num) {

        System.out.println("Example Worked!");

        return;
    }else
        System.out.println("Example Failed!");
}

public static void test2() {

    System.out.println("Finding Number " + locatedNum[0][2] + " With Number " + num);

    if(locatedNum[0][2].equals(num)) {

        System.out.println("Example Worked!");

        return;
    }else
        System.out.println("Example Failed!");

}

public static void test3() {

    String s = Integer.toString(num);

    System.out.println("Finding Number " + locatedNum[0][2] + " With Number " + num);

    if(locatedNum[0][2] == s) {

        System.out.println("Example Worked!");

        return;
    }else
        System.out.println("Example Failed!");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test();
    test2();
    test3();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example works, if you change

```
if(locatedNum[0][2] == ""+num) {
```

to

```
if(locatedNum[0][2].equals(""+num)) {
```

Here, you are comparing `String`s, and `String`s should always be compared using `.equals`. Otherwise, you are comparing the `String` *pointers*, which are most of the time not the same.

Your second test works, if you change

```
if(locatedNum[0][2].equals(num)) {
```

to

```
if(Integer.parseInt(locatedNum[0][2]) == num) {
```

In this case, you are comparing Integer values, and `==` is a valid choice. However, you have to convert your `String` value from `locatedNum` to an Integer value as well.

Your third test works, if you change

```
 if(locatedNum[0][2] == s) {
```

to

```
 if(locatedNum[0][2].equals(s) {
```

If you are comparing strings, always use `.equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: Thank you it worked, I actually laughed because of how close I was and  was surprised to see that you cannot do .equals then an integer but w/e. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example uses == to compare two Strings that are not the same object.  (== says "are you the same object.)  It would work fine with .equals.

Your second is stranger, comparing the String directly to the int without the ""+num conversion you used earlier to convert to a String

Your third has the same == problem.